# Mute/kick channel web application (ARI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, socket.io, asterisk

So I currently have two functions which are called when I add a call to a bridge, and two functions within that get called automatically, so am trying to use JQuery so they only get called when a button is clicked, and then I can work from there in the server side of things.

Issue being at the moment an error gets thrown up saying $ isnt defined.

JQuery does work I have another file am calling which is all JQuery and handles my socket.io client side.

```
 $("#mute").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.mute({
            channelId : 111
        },
            function (err) {});
    });

    $("#kick").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.hangup({
            channelId : 111
        },

function (err) {});
    });
```

As anyone any experience using both or even have any suggestion as to how I can do this.

Full code listing(Server side);

```
var ari = require('ari-client');
var util = require('util');
var chanArr = [];
var test;
var mute;
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//ARI client
ari.connect('http://localhost:8088', 'asterisk', 'asterisk', clientLoaded);

function clientLoaded(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // find or create a holding bridges
    var bridge = null;
    client.bridges.list(function (err, bridges) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        bridge = bridges.filter(function (candidate) {
                return candidate.bridge_type === 'mixing';
            })[0];

        if (bridge) {
            console.log(util.format('Using bridge %s', bridge.id));
        } else {
            client.bridges.create({
                type : 'mixing'
            }, function (err, newBridge) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                bridge = newBridge;
                console.log(util.format('Created bridge %s', bridge.id));
            });
        }
    });

    // handler for StasisStart event
    function stasisStart(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just entered our application, adding it to bridge %s',
                channel.name,
                bridge.id));

        channel.answer(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            bridge.addChannel({
                channel : channel.id
            }, function (err) {
                var id = chanArr.push(channel.name)
                    console.log("Value: " + test);
                test = channel.name;
                updateSip);

                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }

                //If else statement to start music for first user entering channel, music will stop once more than 1 enters the channel.
                if (chanArr.length <= 1) {
                    bridge.startMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else if (chanArr.length === 2) {
                    bridge.stopMoh(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                } else {}

            });

        });
        $("#mute").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.mute({
            channelId : 111
        },
            function (err) {});
    });

    $("#kick").click(function () {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");

        channel.hangup({
            channelId : 111
        },
    }

    // handler for StasisEnd event
    function stasisEnd(event, channel) {
        console.log(util.format(
                'Channel %s just left our application', channel.name));
        console.log(channel.name);

        var index = chanArr.indexOf(channel.name);
        chanArr.splice(index, 1);
        updateSip();
    }
    client.on('StasisStart', stasisStart);
    client.on('StasisEnd', stasisEnd);
    client.start('bridge-hold');
}

//Socket.io logic here
server.listen(3009, function () {
    console.log('listening on *:3009');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + "/testPage.html");
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (data) {
    updateSip();
});

io.sockets.on('muting', function (data) {
    mute = data;
    console.log("client side:" + mute);
});

function updateSip() {
    console.log("Value: " + test);
    io.sockets.emit('sip', chanArr);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how am kicking channels from the bridge.

Am currently working on a Mute & Unmute function, but am having some troubles but this is how I kicked users via the web application

For example.

**Client Side**

When kick button is clicked emit the data found in TD to the server side

```
$(document).on('click', '.kick', function () {
        var hangup = $(this).closest('td').siblings(':first-child').text();
        socket.emit('hangup', hangup);
    });
```

**Server Side**

Store the data received from client side into a var and then call the stasis function.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        updateSip();
        socket.on('hangup', function (data) {
            hangup(data);
        });
    });
```

**Stasis function**

Kick the channel which you have just passed from client to server side using ARI client commands, user will be kicked and will show in stasis application.

```
function hangup(hangval) {
    console.log("Kicked:" + hangval);
    client.channels.hangup
    ({
        channelId : hangval
    },
        function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this helps.